# trigger.io - This bundle is invalid

Tags: trigger.io

I'm finally at a point where I want to export my application for the App Store, but now I'm getting a "This bundle is invalid.  The application-identifier is not formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier: .*"

I'm using Trigger.io to wrap my application, however the only documentation I can find on this error is to do with changing things in xcode, or in the plist file (which I don't know where to find within Trigger on OS X)

Comment: Yes, your distribution provisioning is not setup correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had the incorrect certificate assigned - I had changed the profile within the certificate on the Developer Portal, but hadn't re-downloaded it.  A more detailed messages about what's going on (such as what you're sending and what it's expecting) could have probably fixed this issue a lot sooner.